# How to permanently save the path of the identity file in pgAdmin4

Tags: docker, pgadmin-4

#### Context

I'm using this pgAdmin4 docker image: https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/ in its latest state (version `6.9` at the time of writing).

And I am currently wondering how to permanently set the path of the identity file in the `servers.json` file.

This identity file is mounted as a bind mount in my compose file:

```yaml
- ./id_ed25519:/var/lib/pgadmin/storage/<user_domain>/id_ed25519
```

For the moment, if I set this file path within the running application:

[image: ssh tunnel parameters within pgadmin4]

and if I export that definition in a `test_export.json` file according to the [documentation](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.5/import_export_servers.html), I end up with the following server definition, which curiously doesn't have any reference to the identity file path:

```sh
# cat test_export.json 
{
    "Servers": {
        "1": {
            "Name": "local.pg9",
            "Group": "SERVER",
            "Host": "localhost",
            "Port": 5432,
            "MaintenanceDB": "postgres",
            "Username": "postgres",
            "SSLMode": "prefer",
            "PassFile": "/.pgpass",
            "UseSSHTunnel": 1,
            "TunnelHost": "my-test-server.org",
            "TunnelPort": "22",
            "TunnelUsername": "vpsroot",
            "TunnelAuthentication": 1
        }
    }
```

I also "randomly" tried to guess it by adding `"TunnelIdentityfile": "/id_ed25519"` but it didn't work.

And I cannot find any information about that file in the documentation at https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.5/import_export_servers.html#json-format

#### Question

How could I save the identity file path (ideally in the `servers.json` file) so that I don't have to manually set it up each time I reboot the pgAdmin4 container?

Answer (score 0):

The identity file or passwords are not exported by default for security reasons and will not be restored as well. If you wish to have this then you can raise a feature request on pgAdmin - https://redmine.postgresql.org/projects/pgadmin4/issues/new